# C# List<string> contains partial match from another List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have these lists:

```
var list1 = new List<string>
{
    "BOM_Add",
    "BOM_Edit",
    "BOM_Delete",
    "Paper_Add",
    "Paper_Edit",
    "Paper_Delete"
};

var list2 = new List<string> {"BOM", "Paper_Add"};
```

I want to create a third list of the common items based on a partial match. So, the third list should contain:

```
"BOM_Add",
"BOM_Edit",
"BOM_Delete",
"Paper_Add"
```

because the second list contains "BOM".

If the second list contained "_Edit", then I would expect the third list to have

```
"BOM_Edit",
"Paper_Edit"
```

I know how to do this with `.Intersect()` if I spell out each item (e.g. "BOM_Add") in the second list, but I need it to be more flexible than that.

Can this be done without iterating through each item on the first list? These lists may get very long and I would prefer to avoid that if I can.

Comment: If you want to avoid iterating the list, then you need to know something more about what's in it, and how to compare them. Is the list always sorted? Is the substring always found at the beginning of the string?

Comment: At some point, something has to iterate through the lists even if its a bit of LINQ (It'll still go through the items under the covers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ

```
var result = list1.Where(r => list2.Any(t => r.Contains(t)))
                  .ToList();
```

For output:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output would be:

```
BOM_Add
BOM_Edit
BOM_Delete
Paper_Add
```

> Can this be done without iterating through each item on the first
>   list?

You have to iterate, either through a loop or using LINQ *(which internally iterates as well)*

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done without iterating through each item on the first list?

No, if you want to find all of the items that contain one of the items that you have.  There is no way of building an index, or any sort of structure that can rule out large sections of items without checking each one.  The only option is to compare every single item in the first list with every single item in the other list, doing your `Contains` check.

If you only needed to do a `StartsWith` instead of a `Contains`, then you could sort your list, do a `BinarySearch` to find the item *nearest* to the item that you're searching for, which would allow you to easily find all of the items that start with a particular string while only actually needing to check O(log(n) + m) items (where n is the size of the list an `m` is the average number of matches).  You could do the same thing with an `EndsWith` too, if you just sorted items based on the reverse of the string, but there's no way to sort an items such that a `Contains` check does this.