# Compare DB Item with an List<string> Input

Tags: c#

This is the data from my input

> {Test,Sample}

This is the data from my database

> {C:\Users\Test,D:\DriveB\Sample\Test,C:\Users\Private\Item\LocationB}

My expected output is

> {C:\Users\Test,D:\DriveB\Sample\Test}

How can I get results out using that input? So far I have tried using a for loop like this

```
var Count = Input.Count;

for(var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
   data = data.Where(u => u.Location.Contains(Input[i])).ToList();
}
```

The variable data has already been extracted from the database and has a format like this

- Id
- Name
- Location
- FileType

But the problem is that when it goes past the first loop, it immediately eliminates the second inputs data.

Comment: What is stored inside `data` ? What is inside `FilterInput`? What are the types ?

Comment: What is your expected output ? You did not answer what is inside `Input`  or what is `data` and what type is `Input` ?

Comment: I [tested](https://rextester.com/TTTS84002) and I get the result I expect: the only string that contains both of the input strings. As Shyju says, it's unclear how you get your expected result. I don't understand why you expect "C:\Users\Location".

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that my expected output in the question was wrong. I see that in your results that you got Test only. Would it be possible to get both Test and Sample?

Comment: `data = data.Where(u => u.Location.Contains(Input[i])).ToList();` this replaces the output, you need something like `IEnumerable<String> outputs = db.Where(x => input.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));`? though i do wonder where `C:\Users\Test` comes from..

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (with sample data defined **in the code**).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<string> contains partial match from another List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809832/c-sharp-liststring-contains-partial-match-from-another-liststring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Count = Input.Count;

   data = data.Where(x => input.Any(y => x.Location.Contains(y))).ToList();
}
```

would likely work. The use of `Any` means:

> Get me any row from `data` where **at least one** of the entries from `input` is contained in (i.e. a substring of) the `Location`.

Answer (score 2):

Use split by "," first

```
var input = new List<String>() { "Test", "Sample" };
var db = @"C:\Users\Test,D:\DriveB\Sample\Test,C:\Users\Private\Item\LocationB";
var result = db.Split(',').Where(p => input.Any(c => p.Contains(c))).ToList();
```